# What's a good method/function to create a reversible hash?

Tags: security, hash, encode, reversing

I need to transmit some data over the wire and I don't want that data being plain text.

The text I'm sending needs to be reversed so I can't md5/sha256/etc...

What's a good way to encode a salted string?

Answer (score 6):

You're looking for **encryption**.

What language are you using? You probably have a built-in encryption algorithm you can use.

---

The idea with hashing is that you can only go one-way.

```
[plain text]--->(HASH ALGORITHM)--->[hash]
```

Whereas the idea with encryption is that you can use a *key* together with some *plaintext* to create a *ciphertext*. Then you can use the key on the ciphertext to retrieve the plaintext at any time:

```
[plain text] + [key] --->(ENCRYPTION ALGORITHM)-->[ciphertext]
[ciphertext] + [key] --->(DECRYPTION ALGORITHM)-->[plain text]
```

The decryption algorithm for a given encryption algorithm is usually very similar to the encryption algorithm, and it allows for the retrieval of a plaintext message given a ciphertext and the correct key (ie password).

Comment: Gonna use PHP to whip up the small API

Comment: In particular check this out: http://www.php.net/manual/en/mcrypt.ciphers.php  -->above, someone recommended AES. Take a look at MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_128, it's basically the same thing.

Answer (score 3):

You want to use an encryption function, not a hash - which by definition is one-way.

The [AES](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Encryption_Standard) encryption algorithm would be a good start, as the is probably the most widely used one at present.

Answer (score 0):

You don't want a hash, you want encryption. You should look at [Blowfish](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blowfish_(cipher)).